# how to save and retrieve image in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

How can I save and retrieve an image from a SQL Server database in ASP, VB.NET ?  When I double click on **FileUpload1** control `no Private Sub` comes.  What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a table in a SQL Server 2000 database which has at least one field of type IMAGE.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tblImgData] (

    [ID] [int] NOT NULL ,

    [Name] [varchar] (50) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL ,

    [Picture] [image] NULL 

     ) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]
```

used a file open dialog box

```
this.openFileDialog1.ShowDialog(this);
string strFn=this.openFileDialog1.FileName;
```

using FileInfo class to retrieved the file size

```
FileInfo fiImage=new FileInfo(strFn);
```

Declare an array of that size

```
this.m_lImageFileLength=fiImage.Length;
m_barrImg=new byte[Convert.ToInt32(this.m_lImageFileLength)];
```

By using FileStream object, I filled the byte array

```
FileStream fs=new FileStream(strFn,FileMode.Open, 
              FileAccess.Read,FileShare.Read);
int iBytesRead=fs.Read(m_barrImg,0,
           Convert.ToInt32(this.m_lImageFileLength));
fs.Close();
```

see what you messing!
have fun!

Comment: I have already the code my dear, the problem is on double click on FileUpload1 no 'Private Sub' is coming. So where should i write this code ??

Comment: dear friend,my answer is General.because your question is General.edit your question and add more detail about your problem...when you double click on control in VS you go to aspx source code and see asp.net tag...for go to subroutine please select control and then go to Properties Windows.in this window you must select "event" and in event list you must click DataBinding event,but my advise is create button and use button_click event Instead

Comment: Thanks a lot. It really worked. God Bless You. But openFileDialog is not present in ASP.. Your code works fine in windows app but i need code for ASP vb dotnet..

Comment: My code is based on c#.net...you can alter it for vb.net too..in asp.net you don't need openFileDialog because if you click brwose button it open dialog.example:you can use  string strFn = FileUpload1.FileName; instead of string strFn=this.openFileDialog1.FileName; !have fun dear friend